# How to implement GetObjectData in object with ISerializable field that itself has custom serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, iserializable

What is the correct way to implement ISerializable interface for the class that has ISerializable field?

Assume I have the following two classes, and I have to implement custom serialization for both of them. How should I implement the serialization/deserialization of Foo?

```
public class Foo : ISerializable
{
    private int b;

    private Bar bar;

    protected Foo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        b = info.GetInt32("b") + 1000;
        // How should I instantiate "bar" field here?
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("b", b - 1000);
        // How should I serialize "bar" field here?
    }
}

public class Bar : ISerializable
{
    private int a;

    public Bar(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        a = info.GetInt32("a") + 100;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("a", a - 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the source code? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/serializationinfo.cs,4ade46c59f4e07b4

Comment: @jdweng, I did now, but I don't understand what should I find there? My question is: how do I correctly invoke GetObjectData of the bar field? Or should I just add it as is to the SerializationInfo?

Comment: bar = (Bar)info.GetValue("bar",typeof(Bar)); and info.AddValue("bar", bar);

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for you answer. I tried what you suggested and when trying to serialize the object, I receive the exception:Type 'ConsoleApplication1.Bar' with data contract name 'Bar:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you serializing or deserializing.  I usually try to serialize first and then take the serialize data and deserialize.

Comment: @jdweng, actually now I saw, it works with BinaryFormatter which is good. I would like it to be part of WCF Rest api and thus I used DataContractSerializer to test and had the above problem with it during serialization.

Comment: Why use DataContractSerializer?  Just save the binaryserializer results to the database as a byte[].

Comment: @jdweng, I need to accept Foo as a parameter in WCF. But this, might be a separate topic.